# What is the derivative of $\cos^4(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm not sure if we use the power rule, or if the chain rule is needed for this particular problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but that exponent (the carat ^ symbol) looks like a typo. Did you mean $\cos(4x)$, or maybe $\cos^4(x)$?

Comment: @J.W.Perry Sir, most probably she mean $cos^4x$ otherwise she must not have used ^(as it stands for power sign).

Comment: @Singh Your guess seems most likely.

Answer (score 4):

It's chain rule in this case:
So you have $f(x) = \cos^4(x)$:

So $f'(x) = -4\cos^3(x)\sin(x)$

Answer (score 0):

first think of the rule of power derived from:

$$ (v^k)'= kv^{k-1} v'. $$ 
thus, 
$$ y = ((\cos x)^4) = 4 (\cos x)^3 \cdot (\cos x)', $$ 
and as $ (\cos v)'= - \sin v \cdot v' $, we obtain finally
$$y'=4\cos ^3 x\cdot (-\sin x\cdot 1), $$
i.e.,
$$y'=-4\sin x\cdot \cos^3x $$

Answer (score 0):

It's the chain rule.

If $f(x) = \cos^4(x)$ then $f(x)=g(h(x))$ where $g(x)=x^4$ and $h(x)=\cos(x)$.

Hence $f'(x)=g'(h(x)) h'(x)=4\cos^3 (x) (-\sin x) = -4\cos^3(x)\sin(x)$.